# Кто сталкивался с ошибкой записи в файл? и как решали?

Tags: 1с

выгружаю конфигурацию в файл, прописал путь до нужной мне папки, но не выгружает, пишет

> Ошибка доступа к файлу 'ПУТЬ'. 5(0x00000005): Отказано в доступе.

Далее я разрешил всем пользователям изменять и просматривать эту папку, но эффекта от этого 0, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: *прописал путь до нужной мне папки* Папка сетевая?

Comment: нет, а нужно до сетевой? я все локально делаю

Comment: Не, просто уточняю. А то ж Вы практически ничего не сказали по делу, кроме тривиального "у меня в подполе происходит стук". А так хотя бы одна возможная причина отпала. При условии что "всё локально" - это и приложение, и конфигурация, и БД, и путь выгрузки, и учётная запись, от имени которой выполняется приложение... кстати, а папка назначения пуста? *разрешил всем пользователям изменять и просматривать эту папку* Разрешите конкретно той учётной записи, от которой стартует конфигуратор. Полные права и на папку, и на её подпапки и файлы.

Comment: Если не вылечится - ProcessMonitor в руки, и смотрите, какая операция с каким ресурсом и с каким статусом сбоит. Опять же не факт, что сбоит доступ к каталогу выгрузки - дай на всякий этой учётки права на каталог приложения.

Comment: Уточню: доступ к папке должен быть не только у пользователя под которым стартует конфигуратор, но и для пользователя под которым стартует Агент 1С